# How to set default value for a variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to set a variable to a default value if the assignment returns null or something else.

```
string a = GetValue();
```

if GetValue returns null, then I want to have a default value for variable a, how to do that in c#.  Try not using if.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the null coalescing operator.

```
string a = GetValue() ?? "Default";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = GetValue() ?? "DefaultValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

That will be

```
string a = GetValue() ?? "default value";
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

`string a = GetValue() != null ? GetValue() : "default";`

Comment: Close, but batwad's solution is smoother ;) . Also you need to change it to : "1";

Comment: This evaluated `GetValue()` twice and is uglier than the null coalescence operator `??`

Comment: A "Get" function like `GetValue()` having side-effects probably is a bad idea by itself.

Comment: I agree with CodeInChaos, a getter should cope with multiple calls. The caller may not (and probably should not) know about side-effects [of the getter method].

Answer (score -1):

string a = GetValue() == null ? string.empty : GetValue();

Comment: That is the hard way to do it and `GetValue()` may be called twice.